# CPTXYGraph inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, core-plot

Does anybody know a way to make the axis fixed on a `CPTXYGraph` when the graph itself is inside a `UIScrollView`?

To clarify, I have a `CPTXYGraph` displaying data that is wider than the current screen, so I placed it inside a `UIScrollView` with horizontal scrolling (I'm aware of the `userInteractionEnabled` property core-plot exposes, but I need to keep the acceleration and other benefits of `UIScrollView`). I need the Y axis to be fixed on the left of the screen, something I would usually do in the `layoutSubviews` method of the `UIScrollView`. My first guess was to just apply a transform to the `CPTXYAxis` corresponding to the current `contentOffset` (considering it inherits from `CALayer`), but that seems to have no effect. I've also played around with the `orthogonalCoordinateDecimal` property but it looks like a dead-end.

Is there anybody out there that has managed to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone looking to solve this problem too, my solution:

You can use `CPTConstraints` to position the axis, so I have done the following in my `UIScrollView` subclass:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGFloat xOffset = (self.contentOffset.x >= 0 ? self.contentOffset.x : 0.0f);

    CPTXYGraph *graph = [self graph];
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)[graph axisSet];
    CPTXYAxis *yAxis = [axisSet yAxis];

    [yAxis setAxisConstraints:[CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:xOffset]];
}
```

This code can be repurposed for all fixed axis positions using the different initializers for `CPTConstraints`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[plotSpace setAllowsUserInteraction:YES];
```